# OpenGL/GLUT app on Mac cannot gain focus

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut

I'm running OpenGL in a background thread and using CGL to make sure the current context is getting set correctly (and even using CGLLockContext, etc.). My app renders fine, but the window created by GLUT cannot gain focus. You can't click on it, use keyboard functions, or anything. When the mouse is over the window it will always display a spinning wheel. This is a c++ app running from the command line

Comment: What is "CGL?" Also, unless this happens for every GLUT application, we're probably going to need to see a [minimally functional case that demonstrates the problem.](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @NicolBolas CGL is the interface for the OpenGL implementation for OS X. Updated the question to reflect this. Unfortunately, I can't show code right now :( A pthread is created and all OpenGL/GLUT methods are called from that thread while the main thread does some computations

Comment: "*A pthread is created and all OpenGL/GLUT methods are called from that thread*" Have you considered reversing that, so that the main thread is where the window comes from and the other thread is where the computations are done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! If I use freeglut instead of glut I don't have this issue. I think it arises because glut requires that the `glutMainLoop` is called in the main thread, and freeglut handles calling it in a pthread better